# Hosting domain sub directory on a different server using IIS

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016

Is it possible to host a sub directory on a different server than the rest of the domain?

Server A www.mydomain.com
Server B www.mydomain.com/admin

I know you can easily do this with sub domains, but is it possible with directories

Im using IIS 10

Comment: [Reverse proxy with url rewrite and application request routing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing)

Comment: so to be clear do you want to simply store /admin on a different server or literally have /admin go to a completely different server?

Comment: go to a completely different server

Answer (score 0):

No.

The "www" part is the name of the host computer. Only one computer on the network can use a given host name. And the IP is associated to that name.

What you call a sub-directory is a path on the web application, dependent on the bindings in IIS.

Now, that is using only IIS and windows server. It could, however, be possible using a complex load balancer.